# Ruby Simulated Annealing Trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simulated-annealing

I'm trying to implement a simulated annealing on ruby based on a TSP in which i tried to solve (i converted this code from java). However it turns out the annealing is making my results worst! (PlayerPath gives me a path in which i'll do an Simulated annealing on - i got the path by carrying out a greedy algorithm 1). Can someone help me check on the code and see if i've got something wrong or is it just that simulated annealing doesnt always make things better?

```
#BEGIN ANNEALING
    for i in 1..k
        temp = 10000000
        cooling = 0.003


    if (playerPath[i].length > 2) # if path is larger than 2

      bestPath = playerPath[i]
        while temp > 1
          newSolution = playerPath[i];

          firstPosition = rand(newSolution.length)
          secondPosition = rand(newSolution.length)
      if(firstPosition == 0 || firstPosition == newSolution.length-1)
        next
      end
      if(secondPosition == 0 || secondPosition == newSolution.length-1 )
        next
      end

      # swap cities
      tempStore = newSolution[firstPosition]
      newSolution[firstPosition] = newSolution[secondPosition]
      newSolution[secondPosition] = tempStore

      # Tabulation
      currentEnergy = calculate_distance(playerPath[i])
      neighbourEnergy = calculate_distance(newSolution)

      if(acceptanceProbability(currentEnergy,neighbourEnergy,temp) > rand)
          playerPath[i] = newSolution
          end

      if(calculate_distance(playerPath[i])< calculate_distance(bestPath))
        bestPath = playerPath[i];
      end

      temp *= (1-cooling);


        end

    end

  end


  #END ANNEALING

  #acceptanceProbability
def acceptanceProbability(energy, newEnergy,temperature) 
        # If the new solution is better, accept it
        if (newEnergy < energy)
            return 1.0
        end

        # If the new solution is worse, calculate an acceptance probability
        return Math.exp((energy - newEnergy) / temperature)

end
```

Comment: The whole idea of SA is that is allows to move to a worse solution in order to get out of a local optimum. Of course you will always store the best found solution overall.

Comment: This is a very late comment but hopefully it'll be helpful. While solving a problem using annealing, it's very fruitful and IMHO, indispensable, to track the energy/cost vs iteration number and also energy vs temperature. Just looking at these plots will often give you a lot of insight into what the algorithm is doing. Another trick that helps a lot is not cooling every iteration but every Nth iteration (say, every 100th iteration). Lastly, a very common mistake with SA is to stop too soon! Let is run for many iterations (till the final temperature is a small fraction of the final cost)